# Need to get permanent timestamps for a Google Sheets Dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm trying to build a dashboard for activities in google sheets, for this i have a page where the students can input the activity name and it status:
[Activities page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhs0Y.png)

And i need to get the timestamp for when the activity status has been modified, witch happens in this other page:
[dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLLxP.png)

Where i'am using the flag to lock the time and date that a get with the now() function.
The problems is: every time the page updates, i lose the timestamp. How can I get it permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to achieve your goal:

1. Use the [onEdit

   trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
   to check when a certain cell is manually changed.
2. Check if the cell is from Column `Status` and get the Row.
3. Write the TimeStamp in the other Sheet depending on the value of `Status`

For example:

```
function onEdit(event){

  var editedSheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var eRange = event.range;

  // If the name is Activities and the column edited is A
  if (editedSheet.getName() == "Activities" && eRange.getColumn() == 1){

    var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dashboard = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");

    var dshbValues = dashboard.getRange("B1:L1").getValues(); //Values in Dashboard

    //Compare the value introduced with the Values in Dashboard   
    for (var i = 0; i < dshbValues[0].length; i++){

      //If they coincide, write the timestamp in the row edited, correspondent column
      if (eRange.getValue() == dshbValues[0][i]){

        var timestamp = new Date();

        dashboard.getRange(eRange.getRow(), i + 2).setValue(timestamp);

      }

    }

  }
}
```

> Take into account that the first time you will need to manually run the script to give the needed permissions. Also, the values in Activities Column C and Dashboard Column A need to be in the same order for coherence purposes.

**References:**

- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Get Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Set values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)